# Simple Dockerfile -> Image -> K3s pod -> "exec /bin/bash: exec format error"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ubuntu-20.04

I am deep into learning Kubernetes and K3s and have hit a snag. Step by step:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:latest

# Upgrade RubyGems and install the latest Bundler version
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler && \
    gem install rails

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    micro \
    postgresql-client \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
RUN gem install rails
RUN pwd && ls

# Document that we're going to expose port 3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

rails-pod.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: rails-devenv
  namespace: k3s-test
spec:
  containers:
    - image: pitosalas/rails-image
      name: rails-pod
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
```

Followed by:

```
docker build -t rails-image .
docker tag rails-image pitosalas/rails-image
docker push pitosalas/rails-image
kubectl apply -f rails-pod.yaml
```

--> pod/rails-devenv created

However looking at the pod's log I see this error: `exec /bin/bash: exec format error` which I think has to do with the architecture of the Kubernetes node vs the architecture for which the image was built.

Architectures: I am doing the image build on my computer which is a MacOS M1. The cluster nodes are Digital Ocean droplets running Ubuntu 20.04. That is probably the problem but I don't know where to take it next.

Comment: You can build your images on your Mac [for multiple architectures](https://blog.jaimyn.dev/how-to-build-multi-architecture-docker-images-on-an-m1-mac).

Comment: You need to force Docker to build an x86 image, even though you're on an ARM-based host; the linked question has a couple of ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the `CMD["/bin/bash"]`

CMD executes as soon as the container is up. Here since CMD is /bin/bash which just provides a shell and that's why container exits.

CMD should be the application or process that keeps on running because a container keeps on running as long as the application keeps on running.